# Define a function in R as the division of two other functions

Tags: r

I have defined two functions in R:

```
ftail=makeFun(exp(-x/log(x + exp(1)))~x)

ft=D(1-exp(-x/log(x+exp(1)))~x)
```

I want to define a new function as

```
lambda=ft/ftail
```

but then I get the error:

```
 Error in ft/ftail : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

How is it possible to define a new function using the division of two previously defined functions?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it focuses on programming, debugging, or performing routine operations within a statistical computing platform. Should be asked on SO instead

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a function in the division. f(x) is not a specified value. f(3) is a specified value.
You could define a new function lambda as Indunil says

```
lambda <- function(x){
  return(exp(-x/log(x + exp(1)))/D(1-exp(-x/log(x+exp(1)))))
}
```

or find specific values for a certain x. For example:

```
lambda_for_2 = ft(2)/ftail(2)
```